# Asus Zenfone 5 phone not turning on after factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, boot, asus-zenfone-5

I received an error message on my phone

> Unfortunately, the process.android.process.acore has stopped.

So I have tried to factory reset it. Now it doesn't turn on at all. It just shows the Intel Inside logo. I am clueless about what to do. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, either you can send it to the service center of ASUS as it is still in warranty period, or you can flash the stock rom. But you may have some warranty issues in future if you flash it by your own.

For stock rom and guide visit following.

[Asus Support](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=ASUS%20ZenFone%205&p=39&s=1&os=32&hashedid=96nqlxHp1VKV4Rdz)
[XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/asus-zenfone-5-zenfone-6-to-t2839984)

Answer (score 1):

Can you boot into recovery (power +volume up) if yes then again click reset phone with the help of volume buttons if that doesn't help then either give it to service center(if in warranty)or else flash new stock ROM 
As I know it is having Snapdragon™ 636 processor so how can you get "Intel inside "message well here is a way to flash stock ROM on your phone just make a Google search " Asus zenfone 5 flash stock ROM " and view the top result in video as I can't provide specific tutorials for each device.